# How long should I wait for my avatar to update?

Tags: support

I updated my avatar at gravatar about 16 hours ago. It has not updated here yet.

This is what it should look like:

[image: my new gravatar]

You can see what it actually looks like next to my post.

How long should I have to wait for the avatar to update?

I have cleared my cache, rebooted, logged in an out of EL&U and logged in and our of gravatar, none of these things worked.

The problem seems to be how gravatar cache the URLs. Semantically identical URLs give me different avatars.

Wrong avatar: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ea5fb0bda281e5ddab057950eb17882a?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

Correct avatar: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ea5fb0bda281e5ddab057950eb17882a?s=128&r=PG&d=identicon

I have [posted](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/gravatar-23?replies=5) at the WordPress support forum. I'll let you know if anything comes of it.

Comment: I think MSO has a few posts on this as well

Comment: @ClarkKent - I bet if I delete the old avatar, that won't stop it from appearing. The image is cached somewhere in the gravatar system, cached by precise URL. I have changed the rating of the old avatar to X, but it's still coming up for rating requests of PG.

Comment: I've deleted the old one, let's see what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I have deleted the old avatar, as ClarkKent suggested, and this has had the desired effect.